# Check Data between

Tags: sql, ms-access

New to SO, and I need some basic help to compare two tables in sql, one with the start date, end date, cpy# with the unique ID being the member, to find the cpy# if the member Fdate is in between the start & end date.

**Table1**
[image: Table1]

**Table2**
[image: Table2]

Result should be:

```
Member A FDate 4/12/2018  Cpy# 1234
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. With data sample given, just join tables on Member field. Use WHERE clause: `Fdate BETWEEN StartDt AND EndDt`.

Comment: And what about DA?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and do date comparisons:

```
select t1.*, t2.[Cpy#]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on  t1.Fdate >= t2.StartDt
    and t1.Fdate <= t2.EndDt
```

you can also use `between`:

```
select t1.*, t2.[Cpy#]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t1.Fdate between t2.StartDt and t2.EndDt
```